# how to pass arguments to shell script from AutoSys JIL file?

Tags: shell, autosys

I am new to AutoSys. Need to run Shell script via AutoSys job by passing two arguments (filename & file location). Below are the shell script and the AutoSys JIL file. With this, it didn't work.

Please advise how to pass arguments to shell script from AutoSys JIL file.

**Shell Script (job.sh):**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 filename=$1
 filelocation=$2

 filepath=${filelocation}${filename}
 
 curl --insecure -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'accept */*' \
 -d @$filepath \
 'https://portal/endpoint'

 echo "done"
```

**AutoSys JIL File (job.jil):**

```
 insert_job: JOB_START job_type: cmd
 description: conversion job
 machine: mymachine.net
 owner: ownerid
 max_run_alarm: 0
 alarm_if_fail: y
 send_notification: y
 envvars: ETL_HOME=/tmp/job/job1
 command: /tmp/job/job.sh file1 /tmp/files/
```

Comment: Can you try with command: bash /tmp/job/job.sh file1 /tmp/files/

Comment: Thanks Piyush. Let me try this command